# App on Heroku down with strange log errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

My App is down on Heroku which sucks because we have quite a few users now. The worst part is that I have no idea what the error messages mean...

Does anyone know?

```
2013-05-15T20:55:58+00:00 app[postgres]: [24612-1]  [ORANGE] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2013-05-15T20:55:58+00:00 app[postgres]: [24613-1]  [ORANGE] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 0 buffers (0.0%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.000 s, sync=0.000 s, total=0.004 s; sync files=0, longest=0.000 s, average=0.000 s
2013-05-15T20:56:38+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE measure.current_transaction=28963 measure.db_size=10396472bytes measure.tables=24 measure.active-connections=5 measure.waiting-connections=0 measure.index-cache-hit-rate=0 measure.table-cache-hit-rate=0.99999
```

This is the only thing on the logs. I've read the [Heroku Postgres log statements](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors) but for **checkpoint complete** it says not action needed....

Any ideas? Any help is appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: If your production app on Heroku is down and you think it isn't your fault, then by all means, open an urgent ticket with support!  Whatever your problem is I don't see any indication that it has to do with those log entries.  Are there any other possibly relevant entries?

Comment: I've opened a ticket... Just wondering if stack can make any sense of these entries. No other errors or log entries. Thanks

Comment: That's just routine log output. You probably need Heroku support to examine the instance. If you're lucky you might be able to spawn a follower (streaming replica) and then failover to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the custom domain. Only the A (Host) record on GoDaddy was setup, not the CNAME (Alias). Sometimes a configuration change or deploy can put your app on a different set of EC2 IP addresses, which was the case. So even though the app worked for months without a CNAME, as soon as the EC2 IP address changed the custom domain didn't point there anymore.

I changed the A (Host) record and then added a CNAME (Alias). Now everything is back and working.

Hope this helps someone!